# Custom Headers for Aws Amplify to enable POST and Media

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, http-post, aws-amplify, http-status-code-405

Hi everyone here is are pictures of my custom headers in AWS Amplify and also the errors I am getting. As you can see I have the headers for CORS.

Here is my custom header
[image]

Here is the error I am getting as you can see it is not allowing post. I tested GET and it worked but not post.
[image]

What headers am I missing? Or did I write them wrong? Also FYI this is a MERN application Mongo, Express, React, Node.js.

I would appreciate any help I can get, thanks

Comment: You’re not missing any headers. The 405 response code indicates the cause: The server the request was sent to is saying that it doesn’t support POST requests for that route. And the `Allow` response header shows that is only supports HEAD, DELETE, GET, and PUT requests. So the problem has nothing to do with that CORS config but instead with lack of support for POST requests for that route. That may be because no POST route is configured for that route, or may be some other explicit POST prohibition. The only way for anybody else here to know and help would be to see more of the server code.

Comment: thanks for your input, so I can't use axios.post? that seems weird. so how else would I pass json data to my backend? If you can't use POST then........

Comment: You’d need to configure your backend to support POST requests. Right now it doesn’t support POST requests. So the next step would be go to in an examine the server logs and the server code and figure out why the backend isn’t supporting POST requests, and change it so that it does.

Comment: But it works perfectly locally. I just deployed a build where I replace POST with PUT and same exact error.

Comment: Here is my node.js server side headers. app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'
  );
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  next();
});

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?  I'm encountering the same issue.  Essentially it seems like S3 which is where Amplify is hosting the files is preventing the POST.